# Electrical Wiring for out-building

Tags: wiring, receptacle

Wanting to run power to my storage building. The building is about 100' from the power pole and main breaker box. I am using 10-2 wire on a 30 amp breaker to get power from the box to the building, and then 12-2 wire to wire up the outlets and light. Can 12-2 wire be connected to the 10-2 wire in a junction box?

Comment: How do you plan to provide a disconnecting means for the outlets in the outbuilding?

Answer (score 1):

No, the 30A breaker is not allowed to protect 12-2 [see NEC 240.6 (D)]. One option is to swap out the 30 amp breaker with a 20 amp breaker. Then you would be okay as it sounds like you only want to run some lights and 110 receptacles. The larger wire is good for 30 amps, but you have to protect the 12AWG with a 20. On the bright side, it is very helpful to have that larger 10-2 wire to cover the voltage drop that would otherwise occur over the distance you mentioned. Another option would be to set a fuse box at the end of the 10-2 cable there in the storage building with a 20 amp fuse to protect your branch circuit. That, however, means the 30 amp breaker and wire converts from being a branch circuit to a feeder and you'll have to drive a ground rod at the outbuilding [NEC 250.32(A) with respect to the exception as well].